# T-SQL stored procedure: update local variable inside IF/ELSE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have an `item` table that has a foreign key constraint `customer_id` that references a `customer` table. The `customer_id` column is of type `uniqueidentifier` which needs to be generated on insert (there is no value we could use for this provided by the client). I am created a T-SQL (using SQL Server Express) stored procedure to be called from C# using ADO Entity Data Model to add records to the database.

The objective is to create an item (if it doesn't already exist) with a reference to an already existing customer record or a newly created customer record by using the declared `@customer_id` variable.

Below is a simplified version of my stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspInsertRecord
    @serial_num AS INT,
    @customer_address AS VARCHAR(30)
AS 
    DECLARE @customer_id AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.customer WHERE address = @customer_address)
    BEGIN 
        SET @customer_id = NEWID()
 
        INSERT INTO dbo.customer (customer_id, customer_address)
        VALUES (@customer_id, @customer_address)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT @customer_id = customer_id 
        FROM dbo.customer
        WHERE customer_id = @customer_id
    END

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.item WHERE serial_num = @serial_num)
   BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.item (serial_num, customer_id)
   VALUES (@serial_num, @customer_id)
   END
```

This procedure works for newly created customer records, but not when referencing an existing customer record.

Attempting to add items with an existing associated `customer_id` throws a

> SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'customer_id', table 'dbo.item'

I am fairly new to T-SQL, but this seems to be a scope issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not sure where the rest of your code went, e.g. `END`, but since the error message refers to table `dbo.item` you might want to contemplate why `INSERT INTO dbo.item (serial_num, customer_id)` doesn't supply any variable values. Tip: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Including DDL for the tables helps us help you.

Comment: HABO, thank you for the information. I was transcribing the issue from my work computer and trying to simplify it for the sake of saving time, but it is updated now with the remainder of the sample code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the wrong `WHERE` clause

```sql
        SELECT @customer_id = customer_id 
        FROM dbo.customer
        WHERE address = @customer_address    -- not @customer_id
```

Comment: Yes, Charlieface! My problem was that I was trying to compare a null value with a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER so it was throwing a null pointer exception. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.customer (@customer_id);
```

in your first `IF` block is not a proper SQL statement. Instead:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.customer (customer_id) VALUES (@customer_id);
```

The same issue for your second `INSERT` statement as well. The format here is:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.item (serial_num, customer_id)
  VALUES (@serial_num, @customer_id);
```

Comment: JNevill, thank you for your feedback. Unfortunately that is not the fix, I just forgot to add those lines when I was transcribing it from my work machine to my local machine. I have added the correct code to my example.